# Insert Data into Hypertable

Tags: c#, hypertable

Could anyone please help me out with my issue:
I have created a namespace and a table wit HT4N in C# as follows:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string hql =
               "CREATE TABLE AlarmTable ("
            + "TimeStamp,"
            + "TagId,"
            + "ParameterId,"
            + "Description,"
            + "ACCESS GROUP default (TimeStamp, TagId, ParameterId),"
            + "ACCESS GROUP profile (Description)"
            + ");";

            var cell = new Cell
            {
                Key = key,
                Value = value,
                Flag = CellFlag.Default // optional, CellFlag.Default is the default cell flag
            };



            var connectionString = "Provider=Hyper;Uri=net.tcp://localhost";
            using (var context = Context.Create(connectionString))
            using (var client = context.CreateClient())
            {
                if (!client.NamespaceExists("/IPAA"))
                    client.CreateNamespace("/IPAA");

                using (var ns = client.OpenNamespace("IPAA"))
                {
                    ns.Exec(hql);
                    using (var table = ns.OpenTable("AlarmTable"))
                    {
                        using (var mutator = table.CreateMutator())
                        {
                            //some code here
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Could someone please tell me how do I use the mutator now to create a simple entry in my newly create table, some simple code snippet which makes sense to a newbie would be much appreciated ! 
Thanks,
Neil

Comment: Check out this page (http://ht4n.softdev.ch/index.php/getting-started-in-5min).  Hope it helps.

Comment: Ive been over and over and over this, but can't insert anything in that table. I know its fresh documentation but the examples are really abstract :/

Comment: Maybe this link will help: (http://ht4n.softdev.ch/api-doc/v0.9.7.9/Index.html?topic=html/T_Hypertable_ITableMutator.htm).

Comment: Thanks James, your effort is much appreciated but with all do respect Im looking for a code snippet not documentation. I have all of that and im constantly trying but since im missing some c# knowledge and most of all the syntax for hypertable data insertion....